# How to install and configure awesome wm on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: awesome

I have a brand new install of ubuntu server 16.04.  I'd like to use awesome wm.  Do I need to also install X and lightdm or will it pull them in automatically?  Thanks for your help and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It'll pull everything in automatically, but there is an unfulfilled dependency on libcairo-gobject2 which will show up in ~/.xession-errors if it's needed.

Also if you do not add a login manager you might have to do a little more. I use Slim which just needs /etc/slim.conf to use:

```
login_cmd           exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session
#login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session
#login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session
```

And ~/.xinitrc (but maybe this should use the session passed by Slim)

```
#!/bin/bash
exec awesome
```

Comment: ```apt install awesome``` is not sufficient to get awesome running on ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: @user3751385 - yes, like I said in the answer, you may need to do more. You don't say what issues you are having so it's difficult to help you. Maybe start a new question of your won with more details.